# Call online-convert rest api

Tags: php, curl

I'm using this service [online-convert](http://apiv2.online-convert.com/) trying to make a simple call like in the online-convert sample. However they do not have examples of actual code so I'm kinda in the dark. [online-convert docs](http://apiv2.online-convert.com/#conversion_results/)

I have got that far, here is my best guess at what a call should look like:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api2.online-convert.com/jobs");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Host: https://api2.online-convert.com",
  "X-Oc-Api-Key: <my api key>",
  "Content-Type: application/json"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using a REST API to convert files. Here is an example.

First create a json file with a link where the file you want to convert can be downloaded (uploads are handled differently). Also add the format you want to convert to. Save it as test.json.

```
{
    "input": [{
        "type": "remote",
        "source": "https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png"
    }],
        "conversion": [{
        "category": "image",
        "target": "png"
    }]
}
```

Then send this file using curl to the API of [online-convert.com](http://www.online-convert.com). Add your API key to the script below and save it as start.php in the same directory where you saved the test.json:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api2.online-convert.com/jobs",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => file_get_contents('test.json'),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "content-type: application/json",
            "x-oc-api-key: <your API key here>"
            ),
        )
    );

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
?>
```

Execute the PHP file on the command line with

```
php save.php
```

You can also call the script using a webbrowser.

After you have successfully sent the job and got a valid response, you can obtain the status of the conversion. For this you need the id (job id) you got in the answer when executing start.php. Create a file called status.php and execute it.

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api2.online-convert.com/jobs/<your job id here>",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "content-type: application/json",
            "x-oc-api-key: <your API key here>
            ),
        )
    );

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
?>
```

There you will find the URL to download your file.

The API is much more powerful than that. You can upload files you want to convert, create multiple conversions of one single file (e.g. videos in different resolution with one API call) and set various conversion options.